# Add a notice to users upon first login to the admin area

Tags: theme-development

I'd like to give users a little welcome message on their first login to the admin area. Once they hide the message it should not appear again. I noticed admin_notice is a hook but don't know where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_notice');    
add_action('wp_ajax_hide_my_notice', 'hide_my_notice');

function hide_my_notice(){
  check_ajax_referer('hide-my-notice');
  $user = wp_get_current_user();

  // update status for this user
  $seen_notice = get_option('my_notice');
  $seen_notice[$user->ID] = true;
  update_option('my_notice', $seen_notice);
  exit;
} 

function my_notice(){

  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $seen_notice = get_option('my_notice');

  // already seen it?
  if(isset($seen_notice[$user->ID]) && $seen_notice[$user->ID])
    return;

  ?>
  <div class="updated fade below-h2">
    <p>
      Hi <?php print esc_attr($user->user_login); ?>! Duuuuuude, whatz upp???
      <a class="hide-me"> X </a>
    </p>
   </div>  

   <script type="text/javascript">    

     // this should go in a javascript file;
     // use wp_localize_script() to send variables from PHP to it
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

       $('a.hide-me').on('click', function(){

         $.ajax({
           url: '<?php print admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
           type: 'GET',
           context: this,
           data: ({
             action: 'hide_my_notice',
             _ajax_nonce: '<?php print wp_create_nonce('hide-my-notice'); ?>'
           }),
           success: function(response){ 
             $(this).closest('div').remove();
           }    
         });
       });

     });

   </script>    
  <?php     
}
```

You can also use <strike>[options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)</strike> cookies or [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to store the notice status

Comment: Nice, but why the obscure variable? `$$$` (or is there more to it then that?)..

Comment: no, it's just a variable like any other :)

Comment: Great stuff. Just one more question is how to get it to appear under the H2 like other notices. It has the class below-h2 but doesn't appear there. Thanks.

Comment: does it work if you remove the "below-h2" class?

Comment: Hmm, it appears the notice doesn't get hidden when i come back to the page :P Does it work for anyone else?

How might i go about using the other two methods for hiding it? Sorry i'm in experinced.

Comment: @firefusion: if you're testing on localhost, cookies might not work. Anyway I updated the code to use options.

Comment: The conditional logic for the notice is incorrect, try a modified version of the above: http://wordpress.pastebin.com/76AXTXNs (full credit Ambitious Amoeba - i've simply reworked it a little for you..)

Comment: thank you t31os, I admit I didn't test my code :D

Comment: No problem.... :) Notice i removed the fade and below-h2 classes from the updated div? It's handled interally now(somewhere), the updated messages only need the updated class and the fade effect on update messages was removed(in WP).

Answer (score 2):

WordPress 3.3 has [Pointers](http://theme.fm/2011/09/introducing-pointers-in-wordpress-3-3-2407/) for this.

[image: Example of a pointer]

> WordPress 3.3 is planned for November [2011] and we published the scope a [while ago](http://theme.fm/2011/07/wordpress-3-3-scope-defined-expected-november-15th-1207/) here on Theme.fm. As mentioned in that post, 3.3 will get a series of UI improvements, one of which is Pointers (or Admin Pointers). We learned about pointers in WordPress a few hours ago from one of Daryl Koopersmith’s [changesets](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18707) so we decided to give it a spin ourselves.
>
> **What are Admin Pointers?**
>
> Here’s what Jane wrote in the [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18693) for WordPress pointers:
>
> > When a new user-facing feature is included in a core update, display a new feature pointer that highlights the new feature a la Facebook, Gmail, etc.